# Queue:push() being processed synchronously in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I'm running Laravel 5 and I'm trying to get queue a command.  I'm kicking it off by running:

```
Queue::push( new MyCommand() );
```

To create I command, I did:

```
php artisan make:command --queued MyCommand
```

MyCommand contains a `sleep(20)` and `file_put_contents('test.txt','I work!')`

Command-line I'm running:

```
beanstalkd -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11301 &
php artisan queue:listen &
```

And config/queue.php is set to:

```
'default'     => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'beanstalkd'),

...

'beanstalkd' => [
  'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
  'host'   => 'localhost:11301',
  'queue'  => 'default',
  'ttr'    => 60,
],
```

When I hit the code from the browser, it hangs for 20 seconds and drops the file before completing, instead of returning immediately.

Is there something else I need to do to properly queue a command in the background?

Comment: Sure your `sleep()` call is in the `handle()` method and not the constructor?

Comment: Yes, it's in the handle() function.  I'll update my question with the whole class.

Comment: Just to make sure, you don't have any `QUEUE_DRIVER` value other than `beanstalkd` set in the `.env` file?

Comment: @Bogdan Good call sir!  I forgot all about the .env file.  That fixed it!  Please post your comment as an answer and I'll flag it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure, you don't have any `QUEUE_DRIVER` value other than `beanstalkd` set in the `.env` file. The `env()` method:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'beanstalkd'),
```

will first search for that key in the current eviroment loaded variables, and if there are no matches, it will fallback to the `beanstalkd` value passed as the second parameter.